# Is it safe to post my CV online?

Tags: cv

Is it safe to post my CV online (with my physical address included)?  Should I be worried about identity theft in doing so?

Comment: Identity theft requires information that shouldn't appear in your CV anyway, like your social security number (or equivalent ID number outside the US), your credit card or bank information, or your passwords.

Comment: Surely this is off-topic for here

Answer (score 15):

Considering that public telephone directories with names, addresses, and phone numbers have been around for decades, I don't think there's a significant risk of identity theft here. You could consider using a distinct email for your resume such that if you begin getting too much spam you could manage it separately, but even that's probably not necessary.

Comment: Is there any sense of distinct phone number from personal, work 1, work 2, ...? I am thinking if I should keep my personal phone number in CV, or create a new phonenumber just for business contacts targeted by the CV.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - So long as you answer the phone it doesn't really matter :)

Comment: Yes, but the current case is that I cannot answer all of them. I would like to prioritise my own time, and answer only work calls when time.  - - So I really think I need to get a business phone number for work 1 because I cannot answer all my calls at the moment.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - Keep in mind that the goal of a CV phone number is to let a potential employer contact you. If they have to leave a message or voicemail, that's fine, so long as you get back to them within 48 hours or so. I would not list more than a single number, as it'll just introduce more complexity where it's not needed.

Answer (score 7):

Supporting @eykanal, it is not a big issue since data pertaining to many of the social network accounts are not completely private and many do have access to them for various reasons. One option is to put your university/office address on your CV since your name would in general be there on the university website. Also, as a side point at least do not put your photograph on the CV.

Answer (score 7):

I know many professors and graduate students who post full information in their website copy of the CV, including home address & home/cell telephone numbers.

I don't think posting this kind of information is necessary at all for the online CV. I guess most readers/browsers of your *online* resume are interested in learning about your background, education, honors, grants,  projects, experience,  positions, and publications, rather than calling you on the phone, or paying you a home visit. Including your email adress is enough I guess.

Answer (score 4):

To complement the other answers, very often nowadays home address and home phone can be suppressed, and, indeed, are not "public" information in the U.S.  Workplace contact info suffices.