# Should I put some useful information for phd students on my academic website?

Tags: phd, website

I plan to put on my website useful books and useful journals related to my area, websites covering postdoc opportunities, in other words, information that I think useful in our area especially for phd students. But I am a newbie, not a senior. Do you think it is pretentious or unnecessary?

My motivation is I would be happy and find useful if I read these information on someone else's site.

Comment: Presumably, you mean titles, not PDFs?

Comment: Define "newbie".

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Here are some related questions with many potentially helpful answers: [What contents should I put on my academic website?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3709/69206) and [Is web-presence important for researchers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/616/69206) It will be helpful if you edit your question and make changes there to address the comments above. The more details you provide, the easier it is for others to provide helpful answers.